# How to import text file into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, import, text-files

I need to import [this file](https://vetrina.giocodellotto.it/documenti/storico.zip) into the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tab_sorts](
[row] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[date_sort] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[date_day] [int] NOT NULL,
[date_month] [int] NOT NULL,
[date_year] [int] NOT NULL,
[town] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
[numbers_sort] [nchar](14) NOT NULL,
[nuso_1] [int] NOT NULL,
[nuso_2] [int] NOT NULL,
[nuso_3] [int] NOT NULL,
[nuso_4] [int] NOT NULL,
[nuso_5] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tab_sorts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[row] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm wondering what is the best practice to import the data (I need to split the date into day, month, year and I need to cluster the number comma delimited to perform a LIKE search after using a single % instead of two)

Comment: use bulk insert https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=SQL.120).aspx

Comment: ...and then do the split and search etc. on the data when it is in the table

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra should I change anything to be able to do a full text search in the `[numbers_sort]` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is how i did, super fast way for me:

1. downloaded Notepad++ to open the TAB delimited file in a
   formatted way without altering the structure
2. created a new temporary table to hold the data with essential fields
3. selected the lines from the file i wanted to import, CTRL+C them
4. opened the table as EDIT and selected first row then CTRL+V the
   rows

This solved for me and allowed me to import super fast, now I just need to import this data into my table with relative additional fields (or add the fields to this table and do the job with queries as suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems simple enough but depending on your Version and Tools, if you want a more generic solution, you can use 'Import Data' (Right click on any DB in Management Studio, Tasks->Import Data...).